# How to set a id attribute to button?

Tags: extension, php, smarty

I am creating a button using php pear.

> Button (php code)

```
 $this->addButtons(array(
  /**
   * Array for 'next' button
   */
    array(
    'type' => 'next',
    'name' => E::ts('Next'),
    'isDefault' => TRUE,
  ));
```

> Template code

```
<div class="crm-submit-buttons">
 {include file="CRM/common/formButtons.tpl" location="bottom"}
</div>
```

I want to add a id attribute to that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you cannot set id to a button using php however you can define your own class for the button and use JS to set the id for that class.

Here is the snippet to add class for button

```
$this->addButtons([[
  'type' => 'next',
  'name' => E::ts('Next'),
  'isDefault' => TRUE,
  'class' => 'custom_class', //adding class for button
));
```

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: I want to set a id attribute. Eg <button id="next" />

Comment: Yes, But you cannot add id through php it allows you to add class. You can use class in JS to set id for the button $('. custom_class').attr('id', 'next');

Comment: I tried it but not working.